# Implementing an alternative solution with Pandas `transform`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am analyzing the [TMDB dataset on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata) and the year present in the variable `release_date` on some entries are shifted by 40 years when compared with the variable `release_year`:

```
# Change to pandas datetime
tmdb_df['release_date'] = pd.to_datetime(tmdb_df['release_date'])

tmdb_df.query('release_date > datetime.date(2015,12,31)')[['release_date', 'release_year']].head()
###
#release_date   release_year
#9849   2062-10-04  1962
#9850   2062-12-10  1962
#9851   2062-06-13  1962
#9852   2062-12-25  1962
#9853   2062-10-24  1962
```

I've come up with a solution using `apply`:

```
# Check for movies where the year on `release_date` are shifted
# when compared with `release_yer`
import datetime

# Change to pandas datetime
tmdb_df['release_date'] = pd.to_datetime(tmdb_df['release_date'])

def aux_func(row):
    """Fix year"""
    if row['release_date'].year != row['release_year']:
        return row['release_date'].replace(year=row['release_year'])
    else:
         return row['release_date']

# Apply fix
tmdb_df['release_date'] = tmdb_df[['release_date', 'release_year']].apply(aux_func, axis=1)
```

But I was wondering if it is possible to use Pandas' `transform` to solve this or if there is another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want always same year then first join years with date without `year`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'release_date':['2062-10-04','1980-12-10'],'release_year':[1962,1980]})
print (df)
  release_date  release_year
0   2062-10-04          1962
1   1980-12-10          1980

df['release_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['release_year'].astype(str) + 
                                    df['release_date'].str[4:])

print (df)

  release_date  release_year
0   1962-10-04          1962
1   1980-12-10          1980
```

Comment: Thanks, @jezrael. For what I understand, that will also copy the entries where the years are ok. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think mask is here not necessary. Or something missing?

Comment: I think it is Ok. I was also trying to avoid the entries where the year is the same, but I think it is not necessary. Checking it with `if` or just overwriting them will give the same result. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. One small notice - better is create text data instead pictures, because is problem copied your code. And it is reason for downvotes :(